# How do I get access to the bounds of a view present in ViewController class from another class?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a map drawing app and I need to access the view's bounds from other classes so that I can determine the drawing levels on the map. How would I access the bounds of one the views present in ViewController from another class?

Comment: The view from another class is in the navigation stack or not?

Comment: @ArunK I was asking to access the bound of a view from outside the ViewController class if that makes sense.

Comment: let's suppose you are trying to get the bounds of a viewcontroller that is your previous view controller in the navigation stack, then you can get the bounds by getting the viewcontrollers in the navigationStack and traversing to the viewcontroller and then calling the view's outlet frame.